# Error executing stored procedure fails

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure in mysql database, which fires multiple insert statemets.

As shown below:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_user_group_info
//
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_group_user_info(groupname varchar(50), groupdesc varchar(100), 
createddate varchar(50), createdby varchar(100))
BEGIN
   DECLARE RETURN_VAL INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE NEWGROUPID INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
START TRANSACTION;

   Insert into group_tbl (`groupname`,
   `groupdesc`,
   `groupusers`,
   `createdon`,
   `createdby`,
   `groupstatus`) 
    values
   (groupname,
    groupdesc,
    '1',
    createddate,
    createdby,
    '1');

    SET NEWGROUPID = LAST_INSERT_ID();

   INSERT INTO useringroup_tbl
   ( groupid,
     username,
     regdate,
     joindate,
     userstatus,
     roleid)
   VALUES
   ( NEWGROUPID,
     createdby,
     createddate,
     createddate,
     '1',
     '1');

     INSERT INTO userinrole_tbl
   ( username,
     groupid,
     roleid)
   VALUES
   (createdby, 
    NEWGROUPID,
    '1');

   SET RETURN_VAL = LAST_INSERT_ID();

   SELECT RETURN_VAL;

COMMIT;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

*Schema for tables are as follows*
Table 1 group_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE `group_tbl` 
(
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `groupname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `groupdesc` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `groupusers` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdby` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `groupstatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`groupid`)
);
```

Table 2 useringroup_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `useringroup_tbl` 
(
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `joindate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `userstatus` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `closingdate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `roleid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`groupid`,`username`)
);
```

Table 3 userinrole_tbl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `userinrole_tbl` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `roleid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

While executing this procedure by this statement

```
call insert_group_user_info('test name','test description','2015-05-10 12:10:12','XYZuser')
```

I get an error

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '1-XYZuser' for key 1

and each time it the number appended to the username gets incremented 
like this

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '2-XYZuser' for key 1

So please if anybody can give me direction what I am doing wrong,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably have a unique key in one of those tables.

Comment: @Uueerdo i have truncated all the tables still the same error!

Comment: Second query should be giving you a different error. `createdon` does not exist in a way it can be included in the value list.

Comment: @Uueerdo that was typo , i fixed it in question. But the error is still same!

Comment: Do you have data in the tables? [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/925f9/4)

Answer (score 0):

According to the error you have pasted,

1. `1062 - Duplicate entry '1-XYZuser'` - *PRIMARY KEY  (`groupid`,`username`)* - It doesn't matter if you truncate the tables or not. You might be inserting the same data again.
2. You might be using *last_insert_id()* incorrectly.

Why is there no `auto_increment` in `useringroup_tbl`?